# lsyncd canot update mysql-bin.00001

Tags: mysqlbinlog, lsyncd

I use lsyncd and lsyncd to send file to other server,.sql file is ok,but mysql-bin.00001 canot update.

lsyncd.conf

```
settings {
    logfile      = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile   = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status",
    inotifyMode  = "CloseWrite",
    maxProcesses = 1000,
    maxDelays    = 1
    }

sync {
    default.rsync,
    source    = "/var/lib/mysql",
    target    = "root@192.168.85.173::backup",
    delay = 15,
    exclude = {'ib*','mysql','test','*.cnf','*.sock','performance_schema'},
    rsync     = {
        binary    = "/usr/bin/rsync",
        password_file = "/etc/images.pas",
        archive   = true,
        compress = false,
        verbose   = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like the file mysql-bin.00001 is in use on the target server. Use `lsof | grep mysql-bin.00001` to verify.

Answer (score 0):

update config file : inotifyMode = "Modify". it is worked